# Sharing data between two asp.net mvc 5 application through api when internet connection available

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have 2 project with 2 different database (asp.net mvc 5, oracle). one is warehouse and another is shop. I want to share data between 2 project through api and update database continuously when internet connection available. I don't want any UI to do that, and it will run in background. how can I do that?
Thanks in advance.....

Comment: I think it is bad practice. I recommend you to pick out/create third database/service with such shared stuff which will be used by other services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using Quartz.NET

https://satvasolutions.com/job-scheduling-asp-mvc-quartz-scheduler/

Answer (score 2):

You can create an exe with your update database code in it and schedule that exe in task scheduler, create trigger of running time according to your requirement.

Comment: can you recommend some tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Use a library called Hangfire

[Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/)

It allows scehduling of background jobs, calling window services, you can then have a job to sync the DB's within your code.